# VS 2008 MFC Feature Pack - How do I

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack, document-view

I have an application I'm writing using the MFC Feature pack. It uses Document/View. Since these classes are derived from "normal" MFC classes, these questions may not be Feature Pack specific.

When a change is made, I add an asterisk `*` to the name on the tab, and the word `(modified)` to the main window title using the following code:

```
tabval = "Report_" + pDoc->rptData.reportId.Strip();
winval = tabval;
if (changed) {
    tabval += " *";
    winval += " (modified)";
}
frame->SetTitle(tabval);
frame->SetWindowText(tabval);
name = mainFrame->GetTitle();
mainFrame->SetWindowText(name + " - " + winval);
```

But when changing between tabs, the original text comes back. First question: how do I make the change sticky?

Second question: there's a tree view on the left and a properties window on the right. Switching between them (un)highlights the title bars to show which one is active. The user can also activate and interact with the document window, but there doesn't seem to be any way to give visual feedback that the document window is, in fact, active. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what types your variables are, but as you have `pDoc` and `frame`, I'm assuming that the former is your `CDocument` derived class and the latter is possibly a `CFrameWnd` or `CMDIFrameWnd` derived class.

If I'm not far wrong, then the reason why the tab titles aren't sticking is that you should be calling `SetTitle` on the `CDocument` that's behind each tabbed view, so something like

```cpp
tabval = "Report_" + pDoc->rptData.reportId.Strip();
winval = tabval;
if (changed) {
    tabval += " *";
    winval += " (modified)";
}
pDoc->SetTitle(tabval);    // set tab title on CDocument
```

Comment: That took care of the tab, but the main window title has just the `*` and not `(modified)`. I can live with that if necessary, but is there any way to override that?  Thanks!

Comment: I did some digging, and I found several of ways to modify the main window title, but they are all fairly involved and not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past. The cause of main window's title text changing back is the function [CFrameWndEx::OnUpdateFrameTitle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc665641.aspx). As it is virtual, you can override it on your own derived class to have the behaviour you want. It is a solution that worked for me.