# Remove "Untitled - " from main frame window caption

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC document application where I want to remove the "Untitled - " from the caption.

It way my understanding that I need to remove the 'AddToTitle' property from the window style, and then I can set the title, and the'untitled' string would not be added.

I tried the following, but it does not work.

```
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
 ...

    lpCreateStruct->cx &= ~FWS_ADDTOTITLE;
    this->SetTitle(L"The New Title");
}
```

Anyone know how to remove 'Untitled' from the main window title?

Thanks, 
 -Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnCreate` is simply too late. You have to modify the style before the window is created. Just remove `FWS_ADDTOTITLE` in `PreCreateWindow`.

This is fairly well documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x07xt611.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

From my own answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/35495606/383779

I had a similar problem in the past. The cause of main window's title text changing back is the function [CFrameWndEx::OnUpdateFrameTitle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc665641.aspx). As it is virtual, you can override it on your own derived class to have the behaviour you want. It is a solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is too late but you have a typo in your question

```
lpCreateStruct->cx &= ~FWS_ADDTOTITLE;
```

That should be

```
lpCreateStruct->style &= ~FWS_ADDTOTITLE;
```

And you need to add it in the PreCreateWindow function not the OnCreate function.

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow( CREATESTRUCT& cs )
{
    if( !CFrameWnd::PreCreateWindow( cs ) )
        return FALSE;

    // Eliminate the ability to programmatically change the window title.
    cs.style &= ~( FWS_ADDTOTITLE );

    // Set the window title here!
    this->SetTitle( "Your custom window title goes here!" );

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).